# I am trying to access "C" directory using cmd (Windows 10), but it's not working?

Tags: cmd, windows-10

I am using cmd to access `C` directory in windows 10. But it always go to `C:\Users\LENOVO>`. Actually I have to go to xampp folder in `C` drive. I have tried a few options but could not reach to xampp.
Some of them are:

> C:\Users\LENOVO>C:

This results to `C:\Users\LENOVO>`.
Another one,

> C:\Users\LENOVO>C: cd xampp

This also results the same: `C:\Users\LENOVO>`.

So please help me to access xampp folder which is in `C` drive as the cmd is always on

> C:\Users\LENOVO>

However writing `D:` to cmd go to

```
D:\>.
```

Comment: Use `cd /d C:\xampp` to switch to other directories folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid command.

```
C: cd xampp
```

Use this instead.

```
CD C:\xampp
```

or

```
CD /D C:\xampp
```

The `/D` switch is explained in the help information using `CD /?`. It will also change the current drive letter. If you are currently on a `D:` directory, just using `CD C:\Users\me` will change the current directory on `C:`, but it will not change the current working drive away from `D:`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `cd /` or maybe `cd ../..` 
Both of these options will take you to base directory.

Comment: No, the path separator in Windows is `\ `!

Comment: @aschipfl Yes that's right. That command was for Windows powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Open your command prompt. Write on it **`cd xampp`** then you reach on this folder.